# anybody else experiencing this problem?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm working in visualForce and in Apex classes and in both experience this problem. It's getting quite annoying. Anybody know how to fix?

[image: annoying VisualForce Bug]

Comment: Time to time I have experienced this. I guess this is because the console uses lot of JavaScripts. Full page refresh(Ctrl+F5 in windows) will resolve it some times.

Comment: Thanks for your comment :) I tried that but it doesn't work. It will just disappear at some point then?

Comment: do you have your browser enlarged > 100%? does that with mine if so

Comment: @PhilHawthorn awesome, thanks! didn't even see it :P, it was at 110%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced this issue many time. This issue happens because of browser. Please make sure that in your browser zoom level is set to 100%. You can use CTRL and '+' or '-' button to set zoom level in chrome browser.